# Is there any function for square root of another order?

Tags: c++, math

I have to calculate the sqrt of this number.I don't know what's the name of variable m in english.
[image]

Comment: That's not the *square* root. ... Do you know that taking the n-th root is the same as exponentiating with 1/n ?

Comment: This is called the [geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean), and is also completely off-topic for stack overflow.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's unrelated to programming.

Comment: The main problem with just expressing the mathematical formula directly in C++, is that the numbers can get large, maybe too large. So better express it as a combination of parts.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf The question as stated concerns mathematical notation and terminology only. In what way is that on-topic for SO?

Comment: @MooseBoys - For geometric mean `n` must be equal to `m`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I was about to comment on that. Perhaps the OP really doesn't want geometric mean.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs in http://math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: It might be math that's unfamiliar to programmers, but it's really a programming question: "How do I calculate an mth root?"

Answer (score 6):

Since the product of a large number of numbers can get unreasonably large, it is probably generally best to compute the geometric mean as the exponential of the ordinary arithmetic mean of the logarithms of the numbers.

The C++ standard library provides `log` for natural logarithm and `exp` for exponentation with base *e*. Thus:

```
#include <math.h>

auto geometric_mean( double const* const first, double const* const past_end )
    -> double
{
    double sum = 0;
    for( double const* p = first; p != past_end; ++p )
    {
        sum += log( *p );
    }
    const int n = past_end - first;
    return exp( sum/n );
}
```

Instead of the loop you can use `std::accumulate`.

Disclaimer: code untouched by compiler's hands.

Comment: Good idea, sound like a sound way of avoiding large products.

Comment: Related [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean#Relationship_with_arithmetic_mean_of_logarithms) link. Upvoted for thinking about numerical robustness :)

Comment: `accumulate` works because it can do a left fold, but having to pass `[](double sum, double x) { return sum + log(x); }` as the BinaryOp is rather non-trivial. I'd choose the loop. Personally, I have a `accumulate_transform()` method in my toolbox which accepts a UnaryOp instead.

Comment: @MSalters; Oh, sorry. That was a thinko. Thank you.

Comment: Also, since C++11 we have `log2/exp2` which might be slightly faster. The relation `log(x^c) = c*log(x)` holds in any base, 2, _e_ or 10. Base 2 is easier for computers, _e_ is easier for mathematicians, and base 10 is for engineers ;)

Comment: Great answer; great comments.  This exchange was most educational.  I especially like the enumeration of bases and audiences.  Thank you.

Comment: @duffymo: Some more information here: (http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/27832/is-2x-faster-to-compute-than-expx)

Comment: Just one quibble: I was a mechanical engineer. We'd be as stoked over e as any mathematician.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this `pow(x, 1.0/m)`. It is same with m. root.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following:

```
#include <cmath>
...
double nth_root = std::pow(number, 1.0 / n);
```

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root

`m` is the degree of the root, the product under it the radicand.